# Custom Collections in Doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 1.2.  I'd like to execute a Doctrine_Query that, instead of returning a Doctrine_Collection will return a class of my choosing.  That is, something like

```
$o = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('Foo')
->execute();

$o; //instance of Doctrine_Collection
```

will normally return a generic Doctrine_Collection object.  Instead I'd like it to return  a Foo_Collection object, which I define elsewhere

```
class Foo_Collection extends Doctrine_Collection
{

    public function soSomethingSpecificToAFooObject()
    {
    }
}
```

which will allow me to logically group functionality.

Is this possible?  From my reading and poking at the code base this would seem to have something to do with hydrators, but I haven't been able to a manual page or tutorial that covers what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im pretty sure you can just add the following to your Record's `setUp` or `construct` methods (the table should be available in either one `construct` is run before `setUp` i think though):

```
$this->_table->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_COLLECTION_CLASS, 'Foo_Collection');
```

You can also set this globally on the Doctrine_Connection if you needed to extend Doctrine_Collection and use a different class throughout all models.

Comment: Adding to the setUp method worked for me.  Thanks to both of you for this - very helpful.